# ember-data update data from rest api

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an ember application that consume a Django Rest Api. Data on backend changes frequently(new records are created/updated every minute).
How can I update my data on ember app? I think this is a common pattern in SPA application but I didn't find nothing in official doc that says what is the best approach to this pattern.

After some searches i found two patterns:

- Websockets: this is the only real-time solution but this is to
  complex to implement because of using django on backend and lack of
  knowledge
- Old-style interval polling: this is not real-time but good
  for my needs.

I tried to implement a long polling object according http://yoranbrondsema.com/live-polling-system-ember-js/:

I'm using ember-cli and ember-data.

app/util/pollster.js

```
import Ember from "ember";

var Pollster = Ember.Object.extend({
    interval: function() {
        return 5000; // Time between polls (in ms)
    }.property().readOnly(),

    // Schedules the function `f` to be executed every `interval` time.
    schedule: function(f) {
        return Ember.run.later(this, function() {
            f.apply(this);
            this.set('timer', this.schedule(f));
        }, this.get('interval'));
    },

    // Stops the pollster
    stop: function() {
        Ember.run.cancel(this.get('timer'));
    },

    // Starts the pollster, i.e. executes the `onPoll` function every interval.
    start: function() {
        this.set('timer', this.schedule(this.get('onPoll')));
    },

  onPoll: function(){
    // Issue JSON request and add data to the store
    }
});

export default Pollster;
```

app/routes/test.js

```
setupController: function(controller, model) { 
    if (Ember.isNone(this.get('pollster'))) {
        this.set('pollster', Pollster.create({
            controller: controller
            onPoll: function() {
                this.controller.set('model', this.controller.store.find('mymodel',}));
            }
        }));
    }
    this.get('pollster').start();
},
deactivate: function() {
    this.get('pollster').stop();
},
.....
```

Q1: It seems to work but is this the best approach?
Q2: Also, when the 'onPoll' function is execute i see a 'flickering' on my template. I think it's due to the fact that records of the model are deleted and recreated but it's very annoying. It's possible to avoid this behavior?
Q3: where to store custom objects in emberjs? Like Pollster?

Comment: Try setting the model in app/route/test.js to `this.store.find('mymodel')` and in the onPoll function just do again a `this.store.find('mymodel')`. I guess this should avoid your flickering.

Comment: If i use 'this.store.find('mymodel')' in onPoll I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined`.  In setupController I do `var _this = this;` and inside  onPoll `_this.store.find('mymodel')`. But templates doesn't update.

Comment: Did you set the model in the routes model hook?

Comment: @StefanKoenig yes. In my TestRoute i have this code `model: function(){
    return this.store.find('mymodel',);
  },`

Comment: We are using a simpler setup for polling, basically it consists of a route setting the model like you did in the model hook and starting a poller in setupController like `setInterval((function() { _this.store.find('mymodel'); }), 60000)`. Embers bindings should take care of the rest. Maybe try it this way first and implement the recommended Ember.run.later version afterwards?

Comment: @StefanKoenig i've tried how you suggest but nothing to do. I still have an annoying flickering when i call store.find. I've found another solution; in model hook i use this.store.filter instead this store.find and inside onPoll function i use `controller.store.find('mymodel').then(function(data){_this.store.pushMany('mymodel', data);});`. And this works in part with no flickering: new records are added and existings are updated. The problem is when a record is deleted from backend. Is there the possibility to tell to pushMany function to remove records for which there isn't an update?

Comment: there is `unloadRecord`, but you have to know wich records you want to unload. You could also do a `unloadAll` before you load the new records, but I guess then you will have a flickering UI again. As an alternative, you could mark the (freshly deleted) records as deleted and filter them in the UI.